# Unique decomposition of a vector space into a direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose I have a vector space W that is the direct product of two subspaces, U and V. So:

$W=U\oplus V$

My working definition of direct product is that $W = U + V$ and $U\cap V = 0$.

Now my problem is showing that once U is defined, V is unique. I have tried to proceed as follows:

Suppose $W=U\oplus V$, $W=U\oplus V'$

Then if $ V \neq V'$, we can assume there is an element $x \in V $ that is not in $V'$. This $x$ also cannot be in $U$.

So if we have $w\in W$ such that $w=x$ then $w=u+v'$ as well, with $u\in U$ and $v' \in V'$. So:

$ w = u+v' = x$

But I can't find a contradiction. If possible I would like to show this without using theorems about orthogonality. Thank you!

Edit: Also $dim(W) = dim(V) + dim(U)$

Comment: You can't find it because there's really no contradiction. In general case (i.e., without orthogonality condition) decomposition is not unique.

Comment: Yep, realized that. Thank you! In my head I was picturing the spaces as orthogonal by default which skewed my understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\Bbb R\times \Bbb R=\langle(1,0)\rangle \oplus \langle(0,1)\rangle$

and

$\Bbb R\times \Bbb R=\langle(1,0)\rangle \oplus \langle(1,1)\rangle$,

but $\langle(0,1)\rangle\neq\langle(1,1)\rangle$

Orthogonality is not negligible in the context of your question.

---

Being a [uniquely complemented lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_lattice) is rather special. I'd like to post a link to [this old paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1945-057-01/S0002-9947-1945-0012263-6/S0002-9947-1945-0012263-6.pdf) by Dilworth which is an interesting read on such lattices.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you are trying to prove is correct. This is an counterexample. Let $W = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $U$ be a subspace of $W$ spanned by $(1,0,0)^t$. If $V$ is spanned by $(0,1,0)^t$ and $(0,0,1)^t$, then easy to check that $W = U\oplus V$. Similarly, let $V'$ be spanned by $(1,1,0)^t$ and $(1,0,1)^t$, then $W = U\oplus V'$. But $V\neq V'$ obviously. Indeed, we can say $V$ is isomorphic to $V'$ as vector spaces. But this statement is rather trivial.:(